# Need to assign Id to new article

Tags: angular

I have articles. But how can i assign article id?
For example: article_1, article_2, article_3
I have model of data

```
export class Model {
items;
constructor(){
    this.items = []
}
```

}

```
export class Article{
title;
body;
constructor(title, body){
    this.title = title;
    this.body = body;
}
```

}

Thx for help.

Comment: A field 'id', like 'title' and 'body' wont do the job? Do you want the name to change each time there is a new instance? How are instances created? Please give some details so people can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Usually IDs are assigned on the back end since the back end has more options available for autogenerating an ID that is guaranteed unique (such as a database sequence).  The way this works is that you POST your new model to the back end (without including an ID) and the back end responds with an updated version of the model that it just saved including any system generated fields such as the unique ID, date/time created, date/time last modified, etc.

You could also randomly generate an ID on the front end, and that might make sense in certain situations, but I wouldn't recommend it in general.